# Data Integration Between JS and Python in Django with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I need to understand a simple call with ajax from JS to Python .I have a python function .This function take a simple parameter and return a result . I want to send this parameter from js ,and get function result to js . I try as below .Python function is ok ,but js side i know i made some wrongs . Here is my python code , function.py :

```
from suds.client import Client as Client
def get_result_by_code(promocode):
url="http://service.emobile.az:8080/ws-loyalty-
program/cp/loyaltyprogram.wsdl"
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.loyaltyProgramCalculate(
       amount=1000,
       authKey='TEST6aede35740f2b9d2248b0ab6b878',
       identicalCode=promocode,
       terminalCode=2166)
if str(result[2])=="SUCCESS":
    status = 1
else:
    status = 0
return status
```

This function return 1 or 0 with promocode .

And my javascript function is below. I know this function is wrong and need to fix:

```
function get_result_by_code() {
promocode = $('#bakcelPromo').val();
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "\docflow\projects\modules_2",
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  data: {"promocode": promocode},
 succes: function (json) {
   $('#output').html(json.message);
}
```

});
 }

And last calculation function in js that will be played on screen is :

```
function calculate() {
   if ( get_result_by_code.val() == 1 )
      calculated_premium = calculated_premium * 0.2
   else  calculated_premium = calculated_premium
   calculated_premium = Math.ceil(calculated_premium)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your example is missing some important bits, like a Django view handler that returns a JSON response. The URL that you're using in the ajax call ("/docflow/projects/modules_2") - is that mapped to a view?

A quick example would be something like this:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/docflow/projects/modules_2$', views.docflow_projects_modules_2_view),
)

# views.py
import json
from suds.client import Client as Client
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


def get_result_by_code(promocode):
    url = "http://service.emobile.az:8080/ws-loyalty-program/cp/loyaltyprogram.wsdl"
    client = Client(url)
    result = client.service.loyaltyProgramCalculate(
        amount=1000,
        authKey='TEST6aede35740f2b9d2248b0ab6b878',
        identicalCode=promocode,
        terminalCode=2166)
    if str(result[2]) == "SUCCESS":
        status = 1
    else:
        status = 0
    return status


def docflow_projects_modules_2_view(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    status = get_result_by_code(data['promocode'])

    result = dict(
        status=status,
        message='Put a message here....'
    )

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

And then in terms of the javascript/frontend, that should look something like this:

```
function get_result_by_code() {
  var promocode = $('#bakcelPromo').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/docflow/projects/modules_2",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    data: {"promocode": promocode},
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.status === 1) {
        // handle success
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
      $('#output').html(response.message);
    },
    error: function () {
       alert('There was an error communicating with the server.');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to write in answer section, as I'm too low on point to make comments yet.

What does it mean "*I know this function is wrong and need to fix*". Doesn't it return any results?

Try to add `error` function callback:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Alternatively check what is in `json` parameter in `success` function (log it with `console.log` or with `alert`.
Also check what is in browser console. Is there any **error message**?